# report link help

Tags: php, javascript, css

We have a page, where we allow people to leave reviews. On any particular page there could be say 6 reviews.

What I have is in each div, there is a report link, allowing other members to report the post. What I want to achieve is quite complex, but wondered if anyone could assist.

Each article, has the report link like:

```
<span class="reportThisLink">
  <a href="report">Report</a>
</span>
```

What I was thinking of doing is adding an id to each link ( dynamically ) so that each review has its own generic ID.
something like: class="reportThisLink" id="article2"

Anyhoo, the questions I have are:

> 1. I want onclick to grab the url of the page, and the ID of the link.
>      And post this info in disabled form fields. ( within a Modal Window ).
> 2. I want to also HIDE the review with a placer div, until the matter
>      has been reviewed.

So questions are , how do i grab the PAGE URL on click and the ID of the link clicked, and post them into disabled form fields ?

And if as a bonus anyone knows how to then HIDE a div that has been reported, I would be pleased to investigate further.

typical page url is: http://anywebsite.com/reviews/state/suburb/

Comment: Gonna have to be an ajax request.  You can get the current page url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in PHP

Comment: Hi imoda , what is "gonna have to be an ajax request" sorry dont understand why ajax request ? do you mean for hiding the div ? The div doesnt need to be hidden until next page refresh if that helps

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want this doing in Javascript on the page? If you're attaching an event to the link.

If so then I'd personally use jQuery and do something like this:

### HTML

```
<span class="reportThisLink">
    <a href="report" id="102" class="reportlink">Report</a>
</span>
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.reportlink').click(function(){
        var docUrl = document.URL; // your current url
        var badLink = $(this).attr('id'); // the id of the clicked link
        // Now you could do the rest as you said 
        // and put these values into hidden form fields.
        // Or you could submit them via "post" using jQuery...
        $.post('reporthandler.php', {offendingUrl: docUrl, offendingLink: badLink});
    });
});
```

### Caveat

I've not tested this for typos so beware there may be a few errors. For more info its worth checking out jQuery: http://www.jquery.com

Comment: Thanks, will do some testing today with this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't forget to hide the element: `$('#the_element').hide();` Since I'm not sure how you have your pages designed, I'll leave it at simplest form.